Pytest - Mocking a single line in python function
I'm doing tests for my function but I have one line calling my config mongo uri path and I need to mock this one but I don't know how.
def get_indexes(collection, database, criterias):
    file = database.files.find_one(
        {"_id": bson.ObjectId(collection)}, {"_id": 0, "internal_name": 1})["internal_name"]
    server = MongoClient(import_configuration("mongodb", "uri"))
    database_data = server["db_data"]
    indexes = database_data[file].index_information()

    fields_names = []
    for criteria in criterias:
        field = database.champs.find_one(
            {"_id": criteria["field"]}, {"_id": 0, "internal_name": 1})["internal_name"]
        fields_names.append(field)

    names_joined = ""
    for field in fields_names:
        names_joined +=  f"{field}_1"

    if names_joined in indexes:
        return True

    return False

What I'm doing in my tests is:
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def database():
    client = mongomock.MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27016/")
    db = client.db
    db_data = client.db_data

    # Files
    objects = [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("65afa95dbd2214f7afa80aa6"),
            "internal_name": "test",
            "name": "toto",
            "percent_s": 80,
            "percent_m": 50
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("65afa95dbd2214f7afa80aa7"),
            "internal_name": "test2",
            "name": "titi",
            "percent_s": 45,
            "percent_m": 12
        },
    ]
    db.fichiers.insert_many(objects)
    file = db.files.find_one({"_id": ObjectId("65afa95dbd2214f7afa80aa6")}, {"_id": 0, "internal_name": 1})["internal_name"]

    # Champs
    objects = [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("65afa95dbd2214f7afa80aa8"),
            "internal_name": "name"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("65afa95dbd2214f7afa80aa9"),
            "internal_name": "test2"
        },
    ]
    db.fields.insert_many(objects)

    # db_data file
    objects = [
        {
            "_id": "idindividu01",
            "_idhouse": "idfoyer01",
            "index": "index"
        },
        {
            "_id": "idindividu02",
            "_idhouse": "idfoyer02",
            "index": "index"
        }
    ]
    db_data[file].insert_many(objects)
    collection = db_data[file]
    collection.create_index([("index", ASCENDING)], background=False)

    return db, db_data

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "collection,criterias,expected",
    [
        (ObjectId("65afa95dbd2214f7afa80aa6"), [{"champ": ObjectId("65afa95dbd2214f7afa80aa8")}, {"champ": ObjectId("65afa95dbd2214f7afa80aa9")}], False),
    ],
)
def test_get_indexes(collection, criterias, expected, database):
    value = get_indexes(collection, database[0], criterias)
    print(value)

I've got my fixture to mock database call but in the function get_indexes I'm calling `db_data` from it and fetching the uri from my config file directly.
server = MongoClient(import_configuration("mongodb", "uri"))

So I wanted to mock that line and use the db_data from my fixture but I don't know how to do it?
I've read multiples post about it but it doesn't seem to be quite my situation.

+1 to what Diego said in his answer below - you should pass in the necessary params instead of having each function retrieve the value themselves. Anyway, you may be looking for something like this: Mocking function within a function pytest? or pytest-mock - Mock a function from a module

Thank you, I'm going to look into these answers too. I'll still make the big changes in the future.

Invoking some constructor inside a function or method might be the indication that you are missing some dependency injection.

def get_indexes(collection, database, criterias, server):
    file = database.files.find_one(
        {"_id": bson.ObjectId(collection)}, {"_id": 0, "internal_name": 1})["internal_name"]
    ...

then, if you have the fiuxture defined
def test_get_indexes(collection, criterias, expected, database, server):
    value = get_indexes(collection, database[0], criterias, server)
    print(value)


Yes, I totally agree with you, but the changes that would be done for this would be consequential. I was thinking about that solution but I wondered if I could just mock that one line. There's no solution about it, then?
